# fopen(../storage/app/public/uploads/profile/6Ay20-05-2023-1684558984.wav failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, laravel-7

I'm using this code

```
  Storage::makeDirectory('/public/uploads/profile/', 0777, true); //creates directory
  $fileOpenPath = '../storage/app/public/uploads/profile/'.$filename;
  $ptr = fopen($fileOpenPath, 'wb');
  fwrite($ptr, $response);
```

this is working on one server but on another server i'm getting this error

> fopen(../storage/app/public/uploads/profile/p6Ay20-05-2023-1684558984.wav):
> failed to open stream: No such file or directory

forlser have `775` permission, i have cleared config also, run composer dump autoload which i found in other links but that solution is not working, on server directory `profile` is created but file is not saved

Comment: @OMiShah Same code i have checked on my local server file is being created at `storage/app/public/upload` and on other server also it is working

Comment: Did you run `php artisan storage:link` ??

Comment: @AliRaza yes i executed this command